# Am I missing something, or do varargs break Arrays.asList?

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

```
  private void activateRecords(long[] stuff) {
    ...
    api.activateRecords(Arrays.asList(specIdsToActivate));
  }
```

Shouldn't this call to Arrays.asList return a list of `Long`s?  Instead it is returning a `List<long[]>`

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

The method signature is consistent with the results, the varargs throws the entire array into the list.  It's the same as `new ArrayList(); list.add(myArray)`  And yes, I know it's meant to be used like this: `Arrays.asList(T t1, T t2, T t3)`

I guess what I'm getting at, is instead of the varargs form, why can't I just have my old asList method (at least I think this is how it used to work) that would take the contents and put them individually into a list?  Any other **clean** way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because long[] and Long[] are different types.

In the first case T is long[], in the second T is Long.

How to fix this?  Don't use long[] in the first place?

Comment: Thanks!  I get it now but working with vendor legacy apps don't give me the option to "[not] use long[] in the first place"

Comment: "Cannot cast from long[] to Long[]"

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to do it one element at a time for the auto boxing to kick in

Answer (score 5):

Autoboxing cannot be done on arrays.  You are allowed to do:

```
private List<Long> array(final long[] lngs) {
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for (long l : lngs) {
        list.add(l);
    }
    return list;
}
```

or

```
private List<Long> array(final long[] lngs) {
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for (Long l : lngs) {
        list.add(l);
    }
    return list;
}
```

(notice that the iterable types are different)

e.g.

```
Long l = 1l;
```

but not

```
Long[] ls = new long[]{1l}
```